# grub-install fails after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 (grub-pc is broken)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, upgrade

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, but during the installation grub-install failed:

[image]

[image]

I continued with the installation and hoped to fix the grub issue afterwards. However, I ran into some difficulties. I have not restarted my system, as I fear that it will not be able to reboot.

This is the error that I always get trying to install grub:

```
 $ sudo grub-install /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1 
 Installing for i386-pc platform.
 grub-install: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1.  Check your device.map.
```

(I also tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` but it also fails with the exact same error messsage.)

The machine seems to use a RAID 1 setup. Here are some information:

```
$ ls -algh /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     120 Aug 12 19:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root    5.2K Aug 12 20:27 ..
crw-------  1 root 10, 236 Jul 28 10:30 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       7 Aug 12 19:41 isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       7 Aug 12 19:41 isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p2 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root       7 Aug 12 19:41 isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p5 -> ../dm-3

$ sudo grub-probe -t device /boot/grub
/dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1

$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003b681

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   468514815   234256384   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       468516862   488390655     9936897    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       468516864   488390655     9936896   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003b681

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   468514815   234256384   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       468516862   488390655     9936897    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       468516864   488390655     9936896   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1: 239.9 GB, 239878537216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29163 cylinders, total 468512768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
fdisk: unable to read /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Especially, the last two lines seem to indicate a deeper problem. :-(

The error message of `grub-install` also mentions a device.map file.

```
$ cat /boot/grub/device.map
cat: /boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
```

I tried to generate it but it did not help either (the error message did not change):

```
$ sudo grub-mkdevicemap
$ cat /boot/grub/device.map
 (hd0)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-00YZCA0_WD-WCAYU7549707
 (hd1)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-00YZCA0_WD-WCAYU7501473
```

Do you have any recommendations what I should try out next? Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Update:**

```
$ debconf-show grub-pc
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf    /passwords.dat: Permission denied
* grub-pc/install_devices: /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0
  grub-pc/kopt_extracted: false
  grub-pc/partition_description:
* grub2/linux_cmdline:
  grub-pc/install_devices_empty: false
  grub-pc/timeout: 10
  grub-pc/install_devices_failed_upgrade: true
* grub2/linux_cmdline_default: quiet splash
  grub-pc/postrm_purge_boot_grub: false
  grub-pc/hidden_timeout: true
  grub-pc/disk_description:
  grub-pc/mixed_legacy_and_grub2: true
  grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline_default: quiet splash
  grub2/device_map_regenerated:
* grub-pc/install_devices_failed: true
  grub-pc/chainload_from_menu.lst: true
  grub-pc/install_devices_disks_changed:
  grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline:
```

Note the line: `grub-pc/install_devices: /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0`

Now the content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume01 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

An backup file from 2012 shows slightly different entries for swap (Volume05 instead of Volume0p5), which indicates that the names could have been changed:

```
 # Note that this is an old file at the time the system was installed (Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10)
 # (This is also the time from which the original grub configuration is from, isn't it?!)
 /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume01 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume05 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

So, maybe it has something to do with "_Volume01" vs "_Volume0p1" vs "_Volume0". `/etc/fstab` says "01", `ls /dev/mapper` returns mappings "0p1", "0p2" and "0p5" (swap), and finally `debconf-show grub-pc` says "Volume0". I think this inconsistency is the root of the problem.

Now I wonder:

1. What should the line `grub-pc/install_devices` in the output of `debconf-show grub-pc` be?
2. How can I change the Grub settings, so I can experiment with different values?

I also just noticed that the installation of grub-pc is broken:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: grub-pc is broken or not fully installed
```

Comment: I really do not know RAID, but your analysis of differences seems to be the issue. The others with RAID I have seen have Volume0 as the equal to the MBR for where to install grub and Volume0p1 as / (root) which it must mount to install correctly. Not sure if somehow numbering changed from just Volume where 01 & 05 were partitions where now it is p01 & p05?? I would try adding the missing p in fstab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the problem:

In a quiet moment, I had time to risk downtime. So I rebooted the system with a Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD and reinstalled Grub. I did not encounter problems and afterwards, the system booted normally.

Here is a general description: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal

From memory, here are the commands that I used in my specific case:

Boot from Live CD and executed the following commands:

```
 $ sudo su
 $ mount /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1 /mnt

 (Sorry, I'm not 100% sure whether the target was /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1 or
  /dev/sda. I think it was /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1.)
 $ grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1
 $ reboot
```

After that, the system rebooted. Finally, I could finish the broken installation with `sudo apt-get install`.

At the moment, `/etc/fstab` still lists `/dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume01` for the root directory. I still don't know if that is actually correct, but I haven't tried to change it to `/dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0p1` to find out whether it still works after a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Installing grub2 in a RAID-setup fails, because device naming is somehow changed with the update, but the runnig system not yet rebooted uses a different naming scheme.

Just cancel grub-install when it failes and reboot. The formerly installed grub still points to a valid kernel and can boot without any problem. After rebooting, grub installs without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant. I had to change only one thing to avoid this error when executing the `grub-install` command:

```
/usr/bin/grub-bios-setup: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB
can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However,
blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/bin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Using your commands above, I changed the grub-install command to install GRUB to the MBR instead of the partition like so (removing the 'p1'):

```
$ grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/mapper/isw_cjccfdbihf_Volume0
```

Otherwise, it really saved my behind and lots of grief. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me so I rebooted and used the [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) to fix the problem. This worked. Whew...!